# Something went wrong when using `\declaretheoremstyle` and `\declaretheorem` in LaTeX 3

Tags: expl3, latex3, thmtools

I want to remove the `.` after the head, i.e., make `headpunct = {}`, but the key `headpunct` is only available in `\declaretheoremstyle`, so I used it to create a new style without `.`, but something goes wrong with it when I used it in LaTeX 3.

Here is an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\declaretheoremstyle
  [
    spaceabove = 3pt,
    spacebelow = 3pt,
    headfont = \bfseries,
    bodyfont = \normalfont,
    headpunct = {},
    postheadspace = { },
    headindent = {},
    notefont = { \fontseries \mddefault \upshape }
  ]{ccnustyle}
\cs_new:Npn \__xdyymath_declare_theorem_with_counter_within:n #1
  {
    \declaretheorem
      [
        style = ccnustyle,
        name =  \clist_item:nn {#1} {1} ,
        refname = \clist_item:nn {#1} {2} ,
        within = \clist_item:nn {#1} {3} ,
      ]
      { \clist_item:nn {#1} {4} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__xdyymath_declare_theorem_with_counter_sibling:n #1
  {
    \declaretheorem
      [
        style = ccnustyle ,
        name =  \clist_item:nn {#1} {1} ,
        refname = \clist_item:nn {#1} {2} ,
        sibling = \clist_item:nn {#1} {3} ,
      ]
      { \clist_item:nn {#1} {4} }
  }
\clist_map_function:nN
  {
    { 定理, 定理, chapter, theorem }
  }\__xdyymath_declare_theorem_with_counter_within:n

\clist_map_function:nN
  {
    { 定义, 定义, theorem, definition }
  }\__xdyymath_declare_theorem_with_counter_sibling:n
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[limit]
  test
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

And the fatal message is

```bash
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between your use and the default setting in thmtools' source code is the catcode of space character.

Within `\ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff`, space is ignored, hence `postheadspace={ }` is equivalent to `postheadspace={}`. While space is a valid value of `postheadspace`, empty is not. To keep a space, use `postheadspace={~}`.

Accepting space (rather than a length) as a special value is the behavior of `amsthm`, see the 3rd note to its doc for `\newtheoremstyle`:

> the 8th argument `<space after theorem head>`<sup>3</sup>
>
> <sup>3</sup> Space after theorem head: `{ }` = normal interword space;
> `\newline` = line break

Related code from `amsthm.sty` (2020/05/29 v2.20.6):

```tex
\newcommand{\newtheoremstyle}[9]{%
  % [...]
  \def\@tempa{#8}\ifx\space\@tempa
    \toks@\@xp{\the\toks@ \thm@headsep\fontdimen\tw@\font\relax}%
  \else
    \def\@tempb{\newline}%
    \ifx\@tempb\@tempa
      \toks@\@xp{\the\toks@ \thm@headsep\z@skip
        \def\thmheadnl{\newline}}%
    \else
      \toks@\@xp{\the\toks@ \thm@headsep#8\relax}%
    \fi
  \fi
  % [...]
}
```

Hence a full doc for `thmtools`' option `postheadspace`, when used with `amsthm`, is actually a length, a space, or `\newline`. Note when used with `ntheorem`, `postheadspace` only accepts a length.

Moreover, `\declaretheoremstyle` will always set options to their default values before processing options given by user, so there's no need to repeat the default settings.

---

A simplified example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\declaretheoremstyle[postheadspace={ }]{style1}
\declaretheoremstyle[postheadspace={~}]{style2}

\declaretheorem[style=style1]{defn1}
\declaretheorem[style=style2]{defn2}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{defn1}
  content % error "Missing number"
\end{defn1}

\begin{defn2}
  content
\end{defn2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the rare instances where the error message `Missing number, treated as zero.` is not misleading. In fact, `postheadspace` has to be number but you set it to `{}`.

From the [`thmtools` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/thmtools/doc/thmtools-manual.pdf):
[image]

Set it to `0pt` instead.

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\declaretheoremstyle
  [
    spaceabove = 3pt,
    spacebelow = 3pt,
    headfont = \bfseries,
    bodyfont = \normalfont,
    headpunct = {},
    postheadspace = 0pt,
    headindent = {},
    notefont = { \fontseries \mddefault \upshape }
  ]{ccnustyle}
\cs_new:Npn \__xdyymath_declare_theorem_with_counter_within:n #1
  {
    \declaretheorem
      [
        style = ccnustyle,
        name =  \clist_item:nn {#1} {1} ,
        refname = \clist_item:nn {#1} {2} ,
        within = \clist_item:nn {#1} {3} ,
      ]
      { \clist_item:nn {#1} {4} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__xdyymath_declare_theorem_with_counter_sibling:n #1
  {
    \declaretheorem
      [
        style = ccnustyle ,
        name =  \clist_item:nn {#1} {1} ,
        refname = \clist_item:nn {#1} {2} ,
        sibling = \clist_item:nn {#1} {3} ,
      ]
      { \clist_item:nn {#1} {4} }
  }
\clist_map_function:nN
  {
    { 定理, 定理, chapter, theorem }
  }\__xdyymath_declare_theorem_with_counter_within:n

\clist_map_function:nN
  {
    { 定义, 定义, theorem, definition }
  }\__xdyymath_declare_theorem_with_counter_sibling:n
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[limit]
  test
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Actually I copy the code from Thmtools Users’ Guide 2020/08/01 v0.72 line 1453-1466. I forgot that the space will be ignored in LaTeX3 environment.